# How to know if an outstanding offer was a product of a buy or a sell offer?

Tags: offer, dex

Is there a way to know from the following response:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/offers/115426014"
        },
        "offer_maker": {
          "href": "https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCOZPRHTQFTBEJSCCYX3T6JAUITJJPSXAABXUGFFTJY4HC4O75YZ4Y22"
        }
      },
      "id": 115426014,
      "paging_token": "115426014",
      "seller": "GCOZPRHTQFTBEJSCCYX3T6JAUITJJPSXAABXUGFFTJY4HC4O75YZ4Y22",
      "selling": {
        "asset_type": "native"
      },
      "buying": {
        "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "asset_code": "USD",
        "asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX"
      },
      "amount": "0.1198350",
      "price_r": {
        "n": 10000000,
        "d": 119834963
      },
      "price": "0.0834481",
      "last_modified_ledger": 25891871,
      "last_modified_time": "2019-09-18T23:55:05Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offer on the orderbook is always a sell offer regardless whether it was created as a result of `ManageBuyOffer`, `ManageSellOffer`, or `ManagePassiveSellOffer` operation. There is no easy way to find out which type of operation resulted in this particular offer creation.

You can analyze all `seller` account operations where `ledger<=last_modified_ledger` though if you really need this information, but that makes sense only if the offer was recently created, otherwise you will end up digging through thousands of operations.